# CSS3 :not() selector ignored by IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-selectors

CSS:

```
input:not([type=submit]):focus,
input:not([type=file]):focus,
textarea:focus {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(67,67,67,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(67,67,67,0.3);
    outline-color:transparent;
    outline-style:none;
}
```

IE9 is ignoring `input:not([type=file]):focus` and styles its box-shadow, background and so on on the input file focus.

Any ideas whats wrong?

**EDIT:**

If its NOT supported: Why is IE9 styling it the like above?
If it IS supported: Why is IE9 ignoring :not() ? and styling it like above?

Comment: did you try `input:focus:not([type=file])`

Comment: According to caniuse.com it is supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=:not

Comment: @Callie It's supported in ie9 http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Comment: please read the edit message. the question is not if its supported or not ;) rather then why is IE9 doing it??? and yes if i remove the code, its not styled anymore on focus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE9 certainly supports the `:not` selector - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=:not) (as mentioned in comments)

**However...**

Your CSS is not doing what you think.

In your current code the second rule:

```
input:not([type=file]):focus
```

overrides the first rule. So the properties will be applied to all input elements except file - but including submit - and in ALL browsers (not only IE9)

Instead you should chain the selectors like this:

```
input:not([type=submit]):not([type=file]):focus, 
textarea:focus {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(67,67,67,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(67,67,67,0.3);
    outline-color:transparent;
    outline-style:none;
    color: pink;
}
```

Checkout this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/55Rzc/2/)**:

...You can see that the input of types submit and file won't get the styles applied on focus, however the input of type button will get the styles applied on focus.

I tested it in IE9 and it works fine.